# Verilog - Addition with negative numbers

Tags: verilog, negative-number

I'm having a problem where it seems that a negative number is interpreted as positive, and two values are added rather than subtracted. Here's my code:

```
module color_controller(
input [10:0] hcount,
input [10:0] vcount,
 input CLK,
 input [1:0] mux,
 input blank,
 input [1:0] sw,
output reg [7:0] RGB,
 output reg [11:0] x
);

wire [2:0] a;


always @(posedge CLK)
    if(mux == 2'b10)
        x <= x + 1'b1;
    else if(mux == 2'b01)
        x <= x - 1'b1;
    else x <= x;

assign a = {blank, sw};
always @(a)
begin
    case(a)
        0 : RGB = 8'b00111000;
        1 : RGB = 8'b00111111;
        2 : if(hcount > (304 + x) && hcount < (336 + x) && vcount > 224 && vcount < 256)
                    RGB = 8'b11000000;
                else 
                    RGB = 8'b00000000;
        3 : if(vcount < 60)
                RGB = 8'b00000111;
            else if(vcount < 120)
                RGB = 8'b00111000;
            else if(vcount < 180)
                RGB = 8'b11000000;
            else if(vcount < 240)
                RGB = 8'b00111111;
            else if(vcount < 300)
                RGB = 8'b11000111;
            else if(vcount < 360)
                RGB = 8'b11111000;
            else if(vcount < 420)
                RGB = 8'b00000000;
            else 
                RGB = 8'b11111111;
        default : RGB = 8'b00000000;
    endcase
end
```

What I'm trying to do is right now move a box along the x-axis on a monitor. I can get it to move just fine along the positive(right) axis, and to the left, right up until the displacement value x becomes negative.

I think this happens because the 2's comp representation of -1 is FFF, but for whatever reason when it gets to

```
if(hcount > (304 + x))
```

it forgets that x is negative and I get a very large value, such that hcount will never reach it and I will see nothing being displayed.

I tried to fix this by modifying the following code:

```
            2 : if(x[11] == 1'b0)
                if(hcount > (304 + x) && hcount < (336 + x) && vcount > 224 && vcount < 256)
                    RGB = 8'b11000000;
                else 
                    RGB = 8'b00000000;
            else 
                if(hcount > (304 - (~x+1)) && hcount < (336 - (~x+1)) && vcount > 224 && vcount < 256)
                    RGB = 8'b11000000;
                else 
                    RGB = 8'b00000000;
```

I hoped that the additional code would check if x was negative, and switch the operation to be a positive number minus a positive number. Alas, it did not work, and I just don't know why.

Help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In verilog it is the arithmetic which is signed or unsigned rather than the number. The number is just a pattern of bits and can be interpreted however you want.

Verilog only performs signed arithmetic if all operands are signed. `304` is an unsigned decimal forcing unsigned arithmetic. These numbers should also have a width associated with them for improved code readability and relevant warnings when the width is not large enough to represent the value.

try:

```
if( hcount > (12'sd304 + x) )
```

or

```
if( hcount > ($signed(304) + x) )
```